# Cypress - if - else condition doesn't work

Tags: cypress

I need to automate an `if`/`else` condition with Cypress, but it doesn't work in my script. If an `if` element is present (or visible) then click `Yes` otherwise proceed. But in my case, if the first condition is not present the test try to click `Yes` anyway.

```
it('Logout', () => {
      const out = new logout();
      const lged = new logged();
      
      lged.logged().then($button => {
        if ($button.is(':visible')){
          lged.logged().click()
          out.bar().click()
          out.clickout()
        }
        else {
          out.bar().click()
          out.clickout()
        }
      })
    })
```

in my pageObjects I have the class "logged":

```
    class logged {

    logged(){
        return cy.contains('Yes', { timeout: 10000 })
    }
}

export default logged
```

Comment: `lged.logged() ` what does this translate to?

Comment: Hi @AlapanDas thanks.
it defines my variable to manage the case of user already logged and if the user is logged then click "Yes" else...

Comment: Ideally your tests are deterministic and don't rely on the state of the application to perform a specific kind of test. Is there any alternative to doing conditional testing? Perhaps you can elaborate and people can help you to create a testing strategy